# list out the main process in Scrum?

Tags: project-management, project

Scrum is one methodology in agile software development right? What are the main activities in Scrum?

Comment: @kander why didn't you correct "ajail" to agile while you were at it? ;-)

Comment: Because I have < 2000 reputation, so I can retag, but can't edit text yet. I wanted to... believe me, I wanted to... :)

Comment: After I have cleared i was release from Ajail now it is Agile :-))

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), *perhaps* [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the help center's on-topic page for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

I hope this will help.
Nains...

Answer (score 1):

Scrum is indeed an agile software development methodology.

It's more then a set of activities - there are a set of core assumptions and ideas that underlie the activities. Nains' answer contains a cheat sheet explaining very briefly the important concepts.

To answer your question in the most basic sense.

1. Gather user stories
2. Determine priority within these stories, chop them up in small, manageable tasks.
3. Code-code-code
4. Every day: short meeting where team members explain their progress, what they're working on, and where they get stuck on.
5. Every two weeks (or week, or month... depends on your project): deliver a working copy of what you have.
6. Return to step 1.

One such loop is called a Sprint. The essential step is that you begin by revisiting your assumptions what the software needs to do - the user stories, and their priorities.
Also note that this is a short cycle, within a very short period of time, the users get feedback.

Note that there is a lot more to be said about Scrum - if you want more details, I recommend a good book, or at the very least reading the Wikipedia article.